# How do i get app_data on a Facebook page tab using php sdk 5

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token, facebook-tabs

I try to  pass variable like this https://www.facebook.com/testapp/app/appnumber/?app_data=522 in a page tab/app/game and then retrieving the value, using php sdk5 graph api 2.5, is there any solution or even with the facebook js sdk

Comment: do you get any error? did you debug? i guess "testapp" is not an app, but a page name?

Comment: when i get the var_dump ($signed_request); string app_data does not exist

Comment: yeah, that sounds like the bug that is happening right now, it is being discussed in the dev group on facebook right now

Answer (score 0):

Right now there are a series of bugs open for dealing with the app_data parameter, for example:

- https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/408615369335909/
- https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/165446117136338/

The format you chose should work in general, just subscribe to the bugs.